# Failed to run custom build command for `contracts-node-runtime v0.17.0

Tags: ink

I want to setup my local environment for `ink` development and I follow the [link](https://use.ink/getting-started/setup), during execution of `cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag v0.17.0 --force --locked` I got following error:

```
warning: Could not find `Cargo.lock` for `/home/tomek/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/daaac3d/runtime/Cargo.toml`, while searching from `/tmp/cargo-installKPguNj/release/build/contracts-node-runtime-21cc57cc944aa03f/out`. To fix this, point the `WASM_BUILD_WORKSPACE_HINT` env variable to the directory of the workspace being compiled.

error: failed to run custom build command for `contracts-node-runtime v0.17.0 (/home/tomek/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/daaac3d/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/cargo-installKPguNj/release/build/contracts-node-runtime-c001dd92872a3133/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:warning=Could not find `Cargo.lock` for `/home/tomek/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/daaac3d/runtime/Cargo.toml`, while searching from `/tmp/cargo-installKPguNj/release/build/contracts-node-runtime-21cc57cc944aa03f/out`. To fix this, point the `WASM_BUILD_WORKSPACE_HINT` env variable to the directory of the workspace being compiled.
  cargo:warning=Could not find `Cargo.lock` for `/home/tomek/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/daaac3d/runtime/Cargo.toml`, while searching from `/tmp/cargo-installKPguNj/release/build/contracts-node-runtime-21cc57cc944aa03f/out`. To fix this, point the `WASM_BUILD_WORKSPACE_HINT` env variable to the directory of the workspace being compiled.
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: "/home/tomek/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2022-05-23-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/tmp/cargo-installKPguNj/release/wbuild/contracts-node-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.63.0-nightly (b2eed72a6 2022-05-22)


  --- stderr
      Updating crates.io index
      Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate`
  error: no matching package named `pallet-contracts-rpc-runtime-api` found
  location searched: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate
  required by package `contracts-node-runtime v0.17.0 (/home/tomek/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/daaac3d/runtime)`
      ... which satisfies path dependency `wasm-project` of package `contracts-node-runtime-wasm v1.0.0 (/tmp/cargo-installKPguNj/release/wbuild/contracts-node-runtime)`
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `contracts-node v0.17.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git?tag=v0.17.0#daaac3db)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installKPguNj`
```

All previous steps passed smoothly. I would appreciate any advice how to solve it.

PS. The context of the question is that I want to build `Scaffold Ink` repository for `ink` smart contracts, that is why I want to setup installation/configuration process that works smoothly without any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your PS., you could just use [Swanky suite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@astar-network/swanky-cli):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@astar-network/swanky-cli

It allows you to easily scaffold an ink! project, and comes with a node included.

Disclaimer: I'm on the core team.

Comment: Let me check how Swanky can help in solving this: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1330, hm in short, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the [Substrate tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/prepare-your-first-contract/) to setup the installation, following the steps:

1- Open the [Releases](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/releases) page.

2- Download the appropriate compressed archive for your local computer.

3- Open the downloaded file and extract the contents to a working directory.